# Am I using Firestore Indexes correctly?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, indexing, google-cloud-firestore

I've been recently making use of Flutter and Firebase to build some Networking Apps similar to the likes of LinkedIn. One of the App's features is its ability to match your profile with other users registered in the database based on factors such as location and the type of work you do. To do that I've been using Firestore snapshots with some conditions applied. Two of these conditions ask Firebase to sort the users by 'Last Active' and to only read documents of users that have signed in within the past month. In order to declutter the results and decrease the number of documents reads that are requested at a time. This is one example of a firebase snapshot I'm using:

```
Firestore.instance
      .collection('usersIsb')
      .where('Set', isEqualTo: true)
      .where('Account Type', isEqualTo: _tempType)
      .where('Services List', arrayContainsAny: _tempServices)
      .where('Location', isEqualTo: widget.userData.location)
      .where('Last Active', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: widget.dateLimit)
      .orderBy('Last Active', descending: true)
      .limit(10)
      .snapshots()
```

Naturally, because of the complexity of the request, Firebase asks me to create an Index for it, I've done that, and everything seems to be working correctly without any noticeable slowdowns or issues. However, I have a couple of questions that I'd like answered:

1. Are these indexes real-time? As in updated every time a new user document is created?
2. How many Indexes can I have in one Firestore database? The indexing process sounds intensive so I'm assuming there are drawbacks.
3. **Is this how it's supposed to be done in the first place? It feels like I'm doing something wrong...**

**Extra:** [These are the Indexes I currently have enabled in my Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gljLx.png).

This is my first post on the platform so feel free to ask for more information if needed, any advice on how to achieve the objective more efficiently is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> **Are these indexes real-time? As in updated every time a new user document is created?**

Yes

> **How many Indexes can I have in one Firestore database?**

The [documentation on index limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes) says:

> Maximum number of composite indexes for a database:   200

> Maximum number of single-field index exemptions for a database:   200

You should read through the entire documentation there to understand all the limits.

> **Is this how it's supposed to be done in the first place?**

That's a matter of opinion.  You can do whatever you want within the documented limits.  If your indexes and queries work for your use cases, then that's fine.